# AWS batch with fargate job stuck on RUNNABLE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I am using AWS batch with Fargate to run a docker image I built (the job). I have set up everything as the docs specifiy. I checked that my job has vCPU lower then the compute environment etc..
But when submitting a job it remains `RUNNABLE` indefinitely. I saw that Fargate automaticaly uses CloudWatch logs for AWS log events, but when checking, I saw there is only a log group named `aws/batch/job` with no log streams.

Any idea what might cause this (preferably the `RUNNABLE` problem but even only the logs issue can help)? new to AWS batch and fargate and have been searching the internet to found all answers repeating on themselves with no actual insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was Fargate's default CPU limit for my region. I thought for some reason that the limit would be higher, but found out that it is only 6 CPUs per region. When lowered the job definition to 4 CPUs, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: saved my ass. Where did you find this limit?